# Custom breadcrumb navigation, but url link shows page node

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I'm pretty new to Drupal and I'm creating a new content type. The site uses custom breadcrumbs built using BreadcrumbBuilderInterface for certain content types which was built before my time. I'm not very familiar, but it uses route_match. I added my content type to the list and my new pages appear in the breadcrumbs menu now, but I'm not sure why the page's url doesn't show the page title, but instead the page node.

I included a screenshot of the issue. The first screenshot show the page's url as the node of the page, while the breadcrumbs navigation is correct. The page's url should've been the title shown in the breadcrumbs, which is "Kalamera, Inc." The second screenshot shows another content type that uses the same custom breadcrumbs, but the url shows the title of the page which i'm trying to achieve.

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal answers! It sounds like URL aliases for your new content type not setup to create automatic aliases and that no manual alias has been set for that node. Have a look at this introduction to the pathauto module, that you have probably already installed on your site: https://www.specbee.com/blogs/drupal-pathauto-module-brief-tutorial-how-automatically-generate-bulk-url-aliases-drupal-8

Comment: I followed the steps in the article and used [node:title], but when I checked the page, it still shows the node instead of the page title. I checked the list of url aliases, but don't see any of the new pages for my content type listed.

Comment: Never mind, for some reason the bulk generate didn't work to update the aliases, but if I edit the page and selected, "generate url aliase", then the url link updated to the node title. Good thing I'm still working off local, so I'll have to make that edit beforehand when I move it to dev in case the bulk generate doesn't work. Not sure if there's a way to fix the bulk generate, but thanks!